# Why do I get Access is denied on different machine for GetProcesses()

Tags: c#, process

I start processes on various remote servers and I sometimes need to suspend those processes.

Using the code below, I am able to cleanly Suspend and then Resume any process by .exe name, on my workstation.

However, on my remote servers I get "Access is Denied" when try to look within processes:

```
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
        .Where(p => (p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0) && p.MainModule.ModuleName.Equals(exeFile))
        .ToArray();
```

GetProcesses() returns correctly, BUT I cannot access "MainModule"

The entry call is

```
ProcessInfo.SuspendAll("MyAppName.exe");
```

I have read about 32/64 version issues BUT set-up is the same on my workstation as on my servers.

Code:

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Management;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Utils.ProcessInfo
{
    class ProcessInfo
    {

        public static void SuspendAll(string exeFile)
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
                .Where(p => (p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0) && p.MainModule.ModuleName.Equals(exeFile))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                process.Suspend();
            }
        }

        public static void ResumeAll(string exeFile)
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
                .Where(p => (p.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() != 0) && p.MainModule.ModuleName.Equals(exeFile))
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                    if(process.Threads[0].WaitReason.ToString().Equals("Suspended"))
                        process.Resume();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ProcessExtension
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum ThreadAccess : int
        {
            TERMINATE = (0x0001),
            SUSPEND_RESUME = (0x0002),
            GET_CONTEXT = (0x0008),
            SET_CONTEXT = (0x0010),
            SET_INFORMATION = (0x0020),
            QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0040),
            SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (0x0080),
            IMPERSONATE = (0x0100),
            DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (0x0200)
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

        public static void Suspend(this Process process)
        {
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
            {
                var pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thread.Id);
                if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    break;
                }
                SuspendThread(pOpenThread);
            }
        }
        public static void Resume(this Process process)
        {
            foreach (ProcessThread thread in process.Threads)
            {
                var pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thread.Id);
                if (pOpenThread == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ResumeThread(pOpenThread);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need elevated permissions. Make sure you're running the application as an administrator.

Comment: When I run as Admin - I get all sorts of path issues elsewhere

Comment: That sounds like it's just getting farther in the program before encountering a problem. You should try to fix those.

Comment: Well my app has worked for months - until I tried to query processes. Is there no way to get and suspend processes without be Admin? - After all I am only querying processes that I started...

Comment: No, you're querying all processes and then filtering them down by name. That's why you need elevated permissions. You haven't specified what these path issues are so we can't help you with that at this point.

Comment: Can I specify that I only want my processes to GetProcesses()?